# Multiple values in session, but only the first is going to database

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a session that is built by adding options to a product in the shopping cart. (the part that works fine so is not depicted here.)

These options go into a session that is like so: `$_SESSION['options'.$id]` where `$id` is identified before the preceding code block is called.

I am wanting to below code to insert each item in the session as a new row in a database table.

```
foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $option)
{

    echo $option;
    $statement = "INSERT INTO KC_OrderOptions (orderNumber, optionName, productID) VALUES (:orderNumber, :optionName, :productID)";

    $query = $db->prepare($statement);

    $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":orderNumber"      => $orderNumber,
        ":optionName"       => $option,
        ":productID"        => $item
    ));
}
```

Right now with the session I have built, the line `echo $option;` displays the following:

```
Swedish Fish AssortedSmooth n Melty Mints LargeNonpareils Milk ChocolateJelly Belly Sour Assorted
```

It is only placing `Swedish Fish Assorted` into the database. How can I make this loop through and add each item to the database?

Comment: What does the database table look like? Is there a key relationship that might prevent more than one row with the same `orderNumber` or `productID` from being inserted?

Comment: Why do you have `$statement = "INSERT ...` & `$query = $db->prepare($statement);` in the loop? Move those to outside/before the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @futureal -- No there is not!

Comment: @Sean -- How in the world am I supposed to add the options to the database if I take that out? Read the question before commenting... It will help us all out. Thank you.

Comment: @futureal -- I take that back! That was the problem, the orderNumber was defined as the key. I added an `id` column to the table and made that the primary. Ran the script and it worked perfectly! Place in answer please!

Comment: @user3271851 Obviously you don't understand the purpose/value of `prepare()`. You only need to call it ONCE, BEFORE a loop, and then just call the `execute()` inside the loop. Right now you have redundant, unnecessary `prepare()` (and `$statement`) calls. Please read the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php - before posting a question... It will help us all out! Thank you. (ps I never said that is was the answer to your question, just that I wondered why you were setting `$statement` and calling `prepare()` every time in the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct as it is; the most likely culprit is an erroneous key in the database table that is preventing (for example) more than one row with the same `orderNumber` from existing. It could be the case that the `orderNumber` is the primary key, which would certainly cause subsequent inserts to fail.

Regarding prepared statements, and what @Sean alluded to in a comment above, there is no need to re-prepare the same statement for each iteration of the loop (although you certainly can, it's just less efficient). The advantage of preparing a statement a single time and then executing it over and over with different bound parameters is that MySQL can optimize internally for better performance.

Such code might look like:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO KC_OrderOptions (orderNumber, optionName, productID) VALUES (:orderNumber, :optionName, :productID)");

foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $option)
{
    $statement ->execute(array(
        ":orderNumber"      => $orderNumber,
        ":optionName"       => $option,
        ":productID"        => $item
    ));
}
```

Of course, this is an example where there probably isn't much optimization to be had, but doing it this way could probably be considered a best practice.